# Can compilers deduce/prove mathematically?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ml

I'm starting to learn functional programming language like `Haskell`, `ML` and most of the exercises will show off things like:

```
   foldr (+) 0 [ 1 ..10]
```

which is equivalent to

```
   sum = 0
     for( i in [1..10] ) 
         sum += i
```

So that leads me to think why can't compiler know that this is [Arithmetic Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) and use O(1) formula to calculate?
Especially for pure `FP` languages without side effect?
The same applies for

```
  sum reverse list == sum list
```

Given a + b = b + a
and definition of reverse, can compilers/languages prove it automatically?

Comment: FP languages are an extension the lambda calculus just as procedural languages like C are an extension of the Turing machine. In the lambda calculus we have lambda terms, lambda abstractions and lambda applications. By evaluating a lambda application we are simply beta reducing it. Similarly FP languages like Haskell also evaluate applications using reductions (the Hugs interpreter shows you the number of reductions). Hence FP languages are based on the "algebra of lambda calculus", not on the algebra you learned in school. That's why FP compilers don't prove mathematical theorems and optimize

Comment: I believe Coq is a functional programming language used to prove mathematical theorems. However it's not Turing complete. Needless to say it's not based on the lambda calculus.

Comment: @AaditMShah without clarifications, your claim is confusing. The lambda-cube has several vertices, Haskell is only one of them; Coq and Agda are some other vertex. Also, don't be fooled by Turing completeness - it is not a goal to have a Turing-complete languages. The goal is to have languages in which useful programs can be written. There is no use in writing paradoxical programs (except academic).

Comment: You can prove those statements in some functional languages, but you need stronger type system than what Haskell has (for compiler to infer the laws of computation). Then a+b=b+a is no longer "Given", it can be proven from the definitions of (+) and Nat. In a similar way it can be demonstrated that any permutation of the original list produces the same sum. This fact can then be used in places where a+b is required, but b+a is available.

Comment: Indeed, you'd need both commutativity and associativity of (+) for your equation. In general, an arbitrary (+) in Haskell has neither property. Even IEEE floating point numbers unfortunately don't obey some of the usual laws for numbers.

Comment: These are very, very special cases that don't come up a lot in real code.  Real code tends to do folds over much more complicated sequences where no closed form exists, or certainly not one that is known at compile time.  Thus it wouldn't be worth the compiler implementors' time to write such an transformation.

Comment: Many compilers will fold the sum loop to a constant.  Even `gcc` does this.

Comment: Not related to your question but related yo your title: type checking can be interpreted as logical deduction on some particular logic. Check out the Curry-Howard isomorphism and "theorems for free". This idea is the base for some theorem provers such as Coq that some people already mentioned.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Compilers generally don't try to prove this kind of thing automatically, because it's hard to implement.

As well as adding the logic to the compiler to transform one fragment of code into another, you have to be very careful that it only tries to do it when it's actually safe - i.e. there are often lots of "side conditions" to worry about. For example in your example above, someone might have written an instance of the type class `Num` (and hence the `(+)` operator) where the `a + b` is not `b + a`.

However, GHC does have [rewrite rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html) which you can add to your own source code and could be used to cover some relatively simple cases like the ones you list above, particularly if you're not too bothered about the side conditions.

For example, and I haven't tested this, you might use the following rule for one of your examples above:

```
{-# RULES
  "sum/reverse"    forall list .  sum (reverse list) = sum list
    #-}
```

Note the parentheses around `reverse list` - what you've written in your question actually means `(sum reverse) list` and wouldn't typecheck.

EDIT:

As you're looking for official sources and pointers to research, I've listed a few.
Obviously it's hard to prove a negative but the fact that no-one has given an example of a general-purpose compiler that does this kind of thing routinely is probably quite strong evidence in itself.

- As others have pointed out, even simple arithmetic optimisations are surprisingly dangerous, particularly on floating point numbers, and compilers generally have flags to turn them off - for example [Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx), [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-floating-point-precision-844). Even integer arithmetic isn't always clear-cut and people occasionally have [big arguments](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30475) about how to deal with things like overflow.
- As Joachim noted, integer variables in loops are one place where slightly more sophisticated optimisations are applied because there are actually significant wins to be had. [Muchnick's book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Advanced-Compiler-Design-Implementation-Muchnick/dp/1558603204) is probably the best general source on the topic but it's not that cheap. [The wikipedia page on strength reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction) is probably as good an introduction as any to one of the standard optimisations of this kind, and has some references to the relevant literature.
- [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) is an example of a library that does all kinds of mathematical optimization internally. Some of its code is [generated by a customised compiler](http://www.fftw.org/pldi99.pdf) the authors wrote specifically for the purpose. It's worthwhile because the authors have domain-specific knowledge of optimizations that in the specific context of the library are both worth the effort and safe
- People sometimes use template metaprogramming to write "self-optimising libraries" that again might rely on arithmetic identities, see for example [Blitz++](http://blitz.sourceforge.net/). [Todd Veldhuizen's PhD dissertation](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/content/Papers/pdf/VeldhuizenThesis.pdf) has a good overview.
- If you descend into the realms of toy and academic compilers all sorts of things go. For example [my own PhD dissertation](http://urchin.earth.li/~ganesh/thesis.pdf) is about writing inefficient functional programs along with little scripts that explain how to optimise them. Many of the examples (see Chapter 6) rely on applying arithmetic rules to justify the underlying optimisations.

Also, it's worth emphasising that the last few examples are of specialised optimisations being applied only to certain parts of the code (e.g. calls to specific libraries) where it is expected to be worthwhile. As other answers have pointed out, it's simply too expensive for a compiler to go searching for all possible places in an entire program where an optimisation might apply. The GHC rewrite rules that I mentioned above are a great example of a compiler exposing a generic mechanism for individual libraries to use in a way that's most appropriate for them.

Answer (score 11):

### The answer

No, compilers don’t do that kind of stuff.

### One reason why

And for your examples, it would even be wrong: Since you did not give type annotations, the Haskell compiler will infer the most general type, which would be

```
foldr (+) 0 [ 1 ..10]  :: Num a => a
```

and similar

```
(\list -> sum (reverse list)) :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

and the `Num` instance for the type that is being used might well not fulfil the mathematical laws required for the transformation you suggest. The compiler should, before everything else, avoid to change the meaning (i.e. the semantics) of your program.

More pragmatically: The cases where the compiler could detect such large-scale transformations rarely occur in practice, so it would not be worth it to implement them.

### An exception

Note notable exceptions are linear transformations in loops. Most compilers will rewrite

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   ... 200 + 4 * i ...
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0, j = 200; i < n; i++, j += 4) {
   ... j ...
}
```

or something similar, as that pattern does often occur in code working on array.

Answer (score 5):

The optimizations you have in mind will probably not be done even in the presence of monomorphic types, because there are so many possibilities and so much knowledge required. For example, in this example:

```
sum list == sum (reverse list)
```

The compiler would need to know or take into account the following facts:

- sum = foldl (+) 0
- (+) is commutative
- reverse list is a permutation of list
- foldl x c l, where x is commutative and c is a constant, yields the same result for all permutations of l.

This all seems trivial. Sure, the compiler can most probably look up the definition of `sum`and inline it. It could be required that (+) be commutative, but remember that `+`is just another symbol without attached meaning to the compiler. The third point would require the compiler to prove some non trivial properties about `reverse`.

But the point is:

1. You don't want to perform the compiler to do those calculations with each and every expression. Remember, to make this really useful, you'd have to heap up a lot of knowledge about many, many standard functions and operators.
2. You still can't replace the expression above with `True` unless you can rule out the possibility that list or some list element is bottom. Usually, one cannot do this. You can't even do the following "trivial" optimization of `f x == f x` in all cases

   ```
    f x `seq` True
   ```

For, consider

```
f x = (undefined :: Bool, x)
```

then

```
f x `seq` True    ==> True
f x == f x        ==> undefined
```

That being said, regarding your first example slightly modified for monomorphism:

```
 f n = n * foldl (+) 0 [1..10] :: Int
```

it is imaginable to optimize the program by moving the expression out of its context and replace it with the name of a constant, like so:

```
const1 = foldl (+) 0 [1..10] :: Int
f n = n * const1
```

This is because the compiler can see that the expression must be constant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that simple flow analysis should be able to do much more than that. As the list is created with constant variable it could simply allocate a list without creating it. Also since all parameters in the fold are constant, it should be able to run the foldl during compile time instead of running it at runtime.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix This again would require that the compiler has more knowledge about `foldl` and `+` and `enumFromThenTo` than it actually has. For example, it had to know that it is ok to compute `foldl (+) 0 [1..10]` but not `foldl (+) 0 [1..maxBound]`

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing looks like [super-compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9067545/1333025).  In your case, if the expression had a [monomorphic](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism) type like `Int` (as opposed to polymorphic `Num a => a`), the compiler could infer that the expression `foldr (+) 0 [1 ..10]` has no external dependencies, therefore it could be evaluated at compile time and replaced by `55`. However, AFAIK no mainstream compiler currently does this kind of optimization.

(In functional programming "proving" is usually associated with something different. In languages with [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_types) types are powerful enough to express complex proposition and then through the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) programs become proofs of such propositions.)

Comment: Well, maybe no functional language compiler.  Both gcc and MSVC fold the summing loop in the OP's post to a constant.  Certainly any vectorizing compiler does serious code transforms to find vectorization opportunities. While once upon a time these were the province of exotic compilers for high-priced supercomputers, today they are commonplace.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, it's unclear that your simplifications even hold in Haskell. For instance, I can define

```
newtype NInt = N Int
instance Num NInt where
  N a + _ = N a
  N b * _ = N b
  ... -- etc
```

and now `sum . reverse :: Num [a] -> a` does not equal `sum :: Num [a] -> a` since I can specialize each to `[NInt] -> NInt` where `sum . reverse == sum` clearly does not hold.

This is one general tension that exists around optimizing "complex" operations—you actually need quite a lot of information in order to successfully prove that it's okay to optimize something. This is why the syntax-level compiler optimization which do exist are usually monomorphic and related to the structure of programs---it's usually such a simplified domain that there's "no way" for the optimization to go wrong. Even that is often unsafe because the domain is never *quite* so simplified and well-known to the compiler.

As an example, a very popular "high-level" syntactic optimization is stream fusion. In this case the compiler is given enough information to know that stream fusion can occur and is *basically* safe, but even in this canonical example we have to skirt around notions of non-termination.

So what does it take to have `\x -> sum [0..x]` get replaced by `\x -> x*(x + 1)/2`? The compiler would need a theory of numbers and algebra built-in. This is not possible in Haskell or ML, but becomes possible in dependently typed languages like Coq, Agda, or Idris. There you could specify things like

```
revCommute :: (_+_ :: a -> a -> a) 
            -> Commutative _+_ 
            -> foldr _+_ z (reverse as) == foldr _+_ z as
```

and then, theoretically, tell the compiler to rewrite according to `revCommute`. This would still be difficult and finicky, but at least we'd have enough information around. To be clear, I'm writing something very strange above, a dependent type. The type not only depends on the ability to introduce both a type and a name for the argument inline, but also the existence of the entire syntax of your language "at the type level".

There are a lot of differences between what I just wrote and what you'd do in Haskell, though. First, in order to form a basis where such promises can be taken seriously, we must throw away general recursion (and thus we already don't have to worry about questions of non-termination like stream-fusion does). We also must have enough structure around to create something like the promise `Commutative _+_`---this likely depends upon there being an entire theory of operators and mathematics built into the language's standard library else you would need to create that yourself. Finally, the richness of type system required to even express these kinds of theories adds a lot of complexity to the entire system and tosses out type inference as you know it today.

But, given all that structure, I'd never be able to create an obligation `Commutative _+_` for the `_+_` defined to work on `NInt`s and so we could be certain that `foldr (+) 0 . reverse == foldr (+) 0` actually does hold.

But now we'd need to tell the compiler how to actually perform that optimization. For stream-fusion, the compiler rules only kick in when we write something in exactly the right syntactic form to be "clearly" an optimization redex. The same kinds of restrictions would apply to our `sum . reverse` rule. In fact, already we're sunk because

```
foldr (+) 0 . reverse
foldr (+) 0 (reverse as)
```

don't match. They're "obviously" the same due to some rules we could prove about `(.)`, but that means that now the compiler must invoke two built-in rules in order to perform our optimization.

---

At the end of the day, you need a very smart optimization search over the sets of known laws in order to achieve the kinds of automatic optimizations you're talking about.

So not only do we add a lot of complexity to the entire system, require a lot of base work to build-in some useful algebraic theories, and lose Turing completeness (which might not be the worst thing), we also only get a finicky promise that our rule would even fire unless we perform an exponentially painful search during compilation.

Blech.

---

The compromise that exists today tends to be that *sometimes* we have enough control over what's being written to be *mostly* certain that a certain *obvious* optimization can be performed. This is the regime of stream fusion and it requires a lot of hidden types, carefully written proofs, exploitations of parametricity, and hand-waving before it's something the community trusts enough to run on their code.

And it doesn't even always fire. For an example of battling that problem take a look at the source of `Vector` for all of the RULES pragmas that specify all of the common circumstances where `Vector`'s stream-fusion optimizations should kick in.

---

All of this is not at all a critique of compiler optimizations or dependent type theories. Both are really incredible. Instead it's just an amplification of the tradeoffs involved in introducing such an optimization. It's not to be done lightly.

Answer (score 1):

Fun fact: Given two arbitrary formulas, do they both give the same output for the same inputs? The answer to this trivial question is *not computable!* In other words, it is mathematically impossible to write a computer program that always gives the correct answer in finite time.

Given this fact, it's perhaps not surprising that nobody has a compiler that can magically transform every possible computation into its most efficient form.

Also, isn't this the programmer's job? If you want the sum of an arithmetic sequence commonly enough that it's a performance bottleneck, why not just write some more efficient code yourself? Similarly, if you really want Fibonacci numbers (why?), use the O(1) algorithm.

Comment: Indeed! Also, if you want to know whether the sum of a list is the same as the sum of its reverse, think again.

Comment: @Ingo That would depend on whether the data type you're summing implements an associative and commutative addition operator.